# Angular 5 simple form with Action is not working

Tags: html, angular, forms

The code given below is not working in my angular html file but if i use this code individually in an html file it works i don't know what i am doing wrong this is just a simple form .

```
<form action='https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf' method='post'>
    <input  name='storeId' value='4950'>
    <input  name='amount' value='1000'>
    <input  name='postBackURL' value='https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf'>
    <input  name='orderRefNum' value='123113'>
    <input  name='merchantHashedReq' value='6ohsP8x3PpiaI4oNirWGwjVkyMLP4CbzcH6pZwvu9SViOzx9nLxyR/TtJhwFrxBU686Wf1z22G+TBxuo5QkSscuXp266qQWx8AbGWnLXxG79LHt+5VlD+lH2JkjKO997adwVHH6mGNm8ldtAKkRyf/E92QF5PwhWMjq8i4dlbABIjJxnwPS3x13R/Nbfmlugkz7XpX20DmZ0IhPuGBR95sOpDATIjfW51fuStCVVni4='>
    <input  name='autoRedirect' value='0'>
    <input  name='paymentMethod' value='CC_PAYMENT_METHOD'>
    <input  name='emailAddr' value='johndoe@live.com'>
    <input  name='mobileNum' value='0123455500'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
    <input type='submit' value='asdasd' class="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: my angular 5  and cli 1.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 default form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263028/angular-5-default-form-submit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't submit HTML form inside Angular 2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129718/cant-submit-html-form-inside-angular-2-application)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```
<form #form action='https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf' method='post'>
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="form.submit()">Submit</button>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: @HaroonAslam Great, You can accept answer in that case :)

Comment: i will do it in 8 minutes

Comment: form is getting submitted but without values

Comment: @DhireshBudhiraja make sure your inputs are having `name` attribute. You can share stackblitz, I'll check.

Comment: This does not work in Angular 10 and will produce JavaScript error in the console.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `ngNoForm` attribute [as documented](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#description). This will prevent all "magic" Angular behavior, and you will be able to submit the form in the native way (with page reload).

So something similar to:

```html
<form ngNoForm action='https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf' method='post'>
    <input  name='storeId' value='4950'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' value='asdasd' class="btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Posting a form directly causes a page reload, that's usually not what you want in an Angular application (SPA). Grab the data from the form and send an HTTP request from your code to the server instead.

You should leverage the NgSubmit directive, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835516/how-to-submit-form-to-server-in-angular2/34836908#34836908)

Comment: Yeah but there can be scenarios where you don't want a CORS error